# Define in Select

Tags: sql, oracle, variables

I would like to know if there is any way to use the DEFINE command, where I perform a select to pass the value to it.

For example:

`DEFINE data date = select max(date_mytable) from mytable;`

Would there be any way to do this?

The idea is that during the next lines of code to be used, I call the variable instead of being consulted the maximum date of a specific table and having to insert it by hand.

I'm using Oracle SQL

I'm using SQLTools Client

Comment: DEFINE is a sqlplus construct.  what client are you using?

Comment: [Possibly related](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70273792/266304), but it depends on the client, and maybe what you plan to do with the value once you have it (and if you're happy converting between dates and strings). Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70438630/edit) to provide more context.

Comment: I've updated the publication, I hope it's now more contextualized for you. I apologize

Comment: By *"SQL Tools"* do you mean [SQLTools for Visual Studio](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mtxr.sqltools)? That's not an official Oracle product, and it's likely that it's support for Oracle-specific functionality will be limited or flaky. (Caveat: I've never used it myself). In particular I doubt whether it fully supports SQL\*Plus syntax, as that's an Oracle client rather than SQL as such.

Comment: SQLTools.net would be the site where the same client I use is located.

I don't know much about him, it's more of an indication of the people I work with.

But I believe that in fact it doesn't have 100% functionality.

Comment: So what "define" command in SQLTools.net are you referring to?

Comment: ```DEFINE date = '202110'

Select * from mytable
where date = &date```

The defines that I use here, it would be a variable

Answer (score 1):

If you are using PL/SQL, you can define the variable, then use a `SELECT...INTO` statement like this:

```sql
set serveroutput on
set feedback off

DECLARE
    l_date   DATE;
BEGIN
    SELECT MAX (created) INTO l_date FROM all_objects;
    dbms_output.put_line(l_date);
END;
/
```

Comment: I tried using the Pl/SQL command, it runs but returns "PL/SQL BLOCK"

Comment: you need to turn dbms output on if it is not

Comment: You probably need to turn on `serveroutput`. I will edit my answer

Comment: I don't know the background, but I don't think I'll be able to do this activation.

tried running the code you added:

set server output on
set feedback off

got it back:
SET is unsupported. Skipped.

Comment: What are you using to run the query? SQLcl? SQLPlus? SQL Developer? Toad? Java? Python?

Answer (score 0):

We have to use `var[iable]` rather than `def[ine]` to declare a variable because we cannot populate it through use a SELECT statement using `=`.  So in a SQL*Plus session we use variables like so:

```
var data varchar2(8)

select to_char(max(date_mytable))
into :data
from mytable;

select count(*) 
from some_other_table
where some_other_date >= to_date(:data, 'yyyymmdd');
```

Unfortunately SQL*Plus doesn't have a DATE datatype, hence the additional pfaffing around with type conversions.

---

SQL*Plus is an Oracle proprietary client for working with SQL and PL/SQL. Its syntax is **not defined by a standard** (unlike SQL) and consequently many 3rd party client products do not support it, or only support a subset of it. You may find it beneficial to use Oracle's own (free) tools like [SQL Developer](https://www.oracle.com/tools/downloads/sqldev-downloads.html) or [SQL CL](https://www.oracle.com/uk/tools/downloads/sqlcl-downloads.html) (the modern version of SQL*Plus).

Comment: Using the 1st command

```var date varchar2(8)```

I can see the variable that was created. But when I run Select, it gives me an error:

"ORA-01036: invalid variable name/number
"

Comment: That code runs fine in SQL\*Plus. ORA-01036 is an error Oracle hurls when when another sort of client needs to deal with a bind variable and it's not passed properly. This may be an issue with the statement you've written or the SQL Tools implementation for working with bind variables. Impossible for me to tell.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL*Plus, which your particular tools may or may not emulate exactly, you can define a substitution variable from a query using the [`column x new_value y`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqpug/COLUMN.html#GUID-643B665F-B134-4A0B-88F7-10400D6D199E) construction, like this:

```
SQL> column max(object_id) new_value last_object_id

SQL> select max(object_id) from user_objects;

MAX(OBJECT_ID)
--------------
        168843

1 row selected.

SQL> def last_object_id
DEFINE LAST_OBJECT_ID  =     168843 (NUMBER)
```

This marks the specified column name to be tracked as a substitution variable.

Typically in scripts you would give the column an alias matching the desired variable name to avoid the need to copy an exact expression, so you will see things like

```
column today_date new_value today_date
```

followed by a query with a column aliased as `today_date`.

Also notice that it doesn't need to be a single-row query, it just takes the last value returned by query.

With date values, you have to choose the format carefully, because the substitution variable will be a plain text string and not an actual date type. For dates without a significant time I recommend using `'YYYY-MM-DD'` format as it's easier to use it subsequently in date literals using `date '&somevar'`:

```
SQL> column last_created new_value last_created

SQL> select to_char(max(created),'YYYY-MM-DD') as last_created from user_objects;

LAST_CREAT
----------
2021-12-20

1 row selected.

SQL> prompt Last object created on &last_created
Last object created on 2021-12-20
```

Now we can use `&last_created` in date arithmetic:

```
SQL> select date '&last_created' +10  from dual;

DATE'2021
---------
30-DEC-21
```

It's possible that none of this works in the tools you are using, though, as it's a SQL*Plus client feature and nothing to do with SQL itself.